# CSV filename bug concerning dots in Microsoft Query (via Office Excel 2013)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, filenames, query

After hours of struggling it looks like I've found a bug regarding csv file processing by Microsoft Query via Office Excel 2013.

I'm trying to generate a Chart from csv data. Every hour a new record is added so I don't want to import data, but just use the file as a source.

The only working method to at least get dynamic data for a PivotChart was this:
In Excel 2013:
DATA -> From Other Sources ->  -> Enter Name -> Select 'Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv) -> click Connect -> Uncheck 'Use Current Directory' -> click 'Select Directory' -> browse to dir and hit 'OK'.
Then I set some options like delimiting with a semicolon.
Click 3x OK.

Then a window appears where you should be able to select 'Available tables and columns.'

When I use a file containing more dots in the filename then only for the extension, NO columns are listed to choose from. The filename dots are replaced with a number sign (#).
As a test I copied the original file and removed the dots from the filename.

Image here:
[image]

So:

- Data_in_a_file_object1.csv → works.
- Data_in_a_file.object1.csv → doesn't work.

I'm not able to change the csv filenames.

Then at last, the question:
Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround? (I didn't found one.)

Comment: I've found what I need. As new member I need to wait 8 hours to post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued searching and found this: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=60745
So Microsoft Query (and probably other MS products also) expect(s) only one dot in the path plus filename. Typically MS I guess....

My workaround: create a symlink (files are hosted on a linux machine) with only one dot in the name.